# JS - Функция запоминает каждую предыдущею ячейку и добавляет выбранную

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том что функция запоминает каждую предыдущею ячейку и добавляет к ней выбранную, и меняет текст в ней тоже. А мне надо для каждой ячейки отдельно. 
Подскажите в чем проблема или подправьте код.
Спасибо.

```
<div id="left">
        <table id="tableCinema" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" >
            <tr>
                <th >Type</th>
                <th >Name</th>
                <th >Time</th>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>
                <td >1</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>
                <td >2</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>

                <td >3</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>
                <td >4</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
            </tr>           
        </table>

        Change: <input id="changes" type="checkbox" name="" onclick="eventsInTable()"><br>
        Get text for change: <input id="changeText" type="text" name="" value="">

        <button id="applyToChanges">Apply</button>

    </div>
```

---

```
//Выбор ячейки и замена текста
var changeText = function(e){
    var inputChangeText, applyChanges;
    inputChangeText = document.getElementById('changeText');
    applyChanges = document.getElementById('applyToChanges');

    inputChangeText.value = e.target.textContent; //получить текст с ячейки 

    //замена текста
    applyChanges.addEventListener('click', function(){
        e.target.textContent = inputChangeText.value;
    }, false);
} 
//доступ к изменение текста
function eventsInTable(){
    var checkBoxChanges = document.getElementById('changes');
    var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');

    if (checkBoxChanges.checked) {
        table.addEventListener('click', changeText, false);
    } else {
        table.removeEventListener('click', changeText, false);
        alert("You haven't access to change");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в многократном исполнении:

```
applyChanges.addEventListener('click', function(){
    e.target.textContent = inputChangeText.value;
}, false);
```

и выстреливании всех накопившихся обработчиков с соответствующими захваченными `е`.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, после выполнения обработчика я должен удалить его, или "забыть" захваченный `e`?

Comment: @МишаПодлевских Не совсем. Вам не следует добавлять новый обработчик каждый раз, когда выполняется `changeText`, а `e.target` надо в `changeText` запоминать во внешнюю переменную, которую и использовать в обработчике клика для `applyChanges`.